# mysql unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

i'm trying to relate(join or whatever) all tables in my database like this:

```
Select stoktablosu.BarkodNo, marka.markaAd, model.Modelkod, urun.UrunGrubu, renkkod.RenkAdi, stoktablosu.beden, model.sezon,stokguncelleme.adeti ,stoktablosu.StokYeri, toptanfiyat.Tarih, toptanfiyat.AlisFiyati, toptanfiyat.GuncelSatisFiyati, stokguncelleme.eklenencikarilan  
from magazayonetim.marka 
inner join stoktablosu_has_marka on stoktablosu_has_marka.marka_MarkaKod =  marka.MarkaKod  
inner join model on model.marka_MarkaKod = marka.MarkaKod  
inner join renkkod_has_marka on renkkod_has_marka.marka_MarkaKodu = marka.MarkaKod  
inner join renkkod on renkkod.renkkodu = renkkod_has_marka.renkkod_RenkKodu  
inner join marka_has_urun on marka_has_urun.marka_MarkaKod = marka.MarkaKod 
inner join urun on urun.urunKodu = marka_has_urun.urun_UrunKodu   
inner join toptanfiyat on toptanfiyat.BarkodNo = stoktablosu.BarkodNo 
inner join stoktablosu on stoktablosu.BarkodNo = stoktablosu_has_marka.stoktablosu_BarkodNo  
and stoktablosu.BarkodNo = stokguncelleme.BarkodNo
and stoktablosu.renk_renkkodu = renkkod.renkkodu 
and stoktablosu.model_modelkod = model.modelkod
and stoktablosu.urun_urunkodu = urun.urunKodu  
where stokguncelleme.adeti != '0' 
and stoktablosu.BarkodNo  = '01012340138483814İY'  
and marka.markaAd != ' ' and urun.UrunGrubu != ' ' and model.Modelkod != ' ' and stoktablosu.Beden != ' ' and renkkod.RenkAdi != ' ' and stoktablosu.StokYeri != ' ' and model.sezon != ' '
```

but when i execute it i got this error:

> "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'stokguncelleme.adeti' in 'field
>   list'"

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory.

Comment: it means that in table `stokguncelleme` column `adeti` was not found

Comment: the thing is i have stokguncelleme.adeti column in mydatabase table.

Comment: You're just not even joining with that table.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message when trying to insert into a table...the error ended up being caused by a trigger attached to the table (dropping the trigger fixed the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error occurs when specific column doesn't found in any table, but here in your case, You forgot to mention table `stokguncelleme` in `from` clause of your query to join the table.

```
Select stoktablosu.BarkodNo, marka.markaAd, model.Modelkod, urun.UrunGrubu, renkkod.RenkAdi, stoktablosu.beden, model.sezon,stokguncelleme.adeti ,stoktablosu.StokYeri, toptanfiyat.Tarih, toptanfiyat.AlisFiyati, toptanfiyat.GuncelSatisFiyati, stokguncelleme.eklenencikarilan  
from stokguncelleme,     
magazayonetim.marka 
inner join stoktablosu_has_marka on stoktablosu_has_marka.marka_MarkaKod =  marka.MarkaKod  
inner join model on model.marka_MarkaKod = marka.MarkaKod  
inner join renkkod_has_marka on renkkod_has_marka.marka_MarkaKodu = marka.MarkaKod  
inner join renkkod on renkkod.renkkodu = renkkod_has_marka.renkkod_RenkKodu  
inner join marka_has_urun on marka_has_urun.marka_MarkaKod = marka.MarkaKod 
inner join urun on urun.urunKodu = marka_has_urun.urun_UrunKodu   
inner join toptanfiyat on toptanfiyat.BarkodNo = stoktablosu.BarkodNo 
inner join stoktablosu on stoktablosu.BarkodNo = stoktablosu_has_marka.stoktablosu_BarkodNo  
and stoktablosu.BarkodNo = stokguncelleme.BarkodNo
and stoktablosu.renk_renkkodu = renkkod.renkkodu 
and stoktablosu.model_modelkod = model.modelkod
and stoktablosu.urun_urunkodu = urun.urunKodu  
where stokguncelleme.adeti != '0' 
and stoktablosu.BarkodNo  = '01012340138483814İY'  
and marka.markaAd != ' ' and urun.UrunGrubu != ' ' and model.Modelkod != ' ' and stoktablosu.Beden != ' ' and renkkod.RenkAdi != ' ' and stoktablosu.StokYeri != ' ' and model.sezon != ' '
```

That table itself wasn't found in join, so its giving you an error like `column not found`

**EDIT:**  changed order of join with `stoktablosu` table.

```
Select stoktablosu.BarkodNo, marka.markaAd, model.Modelkod, urun.UrunGrubu, renkkod.RenkAdi, stoktablosu.beden, model.sezon,stokguncelleme.adeti ,stoktablosu.StokYeri, toptanfiyat.Tarih, toptanfiyat.AlisFiyati, toptanfiyat.GuncelSatisFiyati, stokguncelleme.eklenencikarilan  
from stokguncelleme,     
magazayonetim.marka 
inner join stoktablosu_has_marka on stoktablosu_has_marka.marka_MarkaKod =  marka.MarkaKod  
inner join model on model.marka_MarkaKod = marka.MarkaKod  
inner join renkkod_has_marka on renkkod_has_marka.marka_MarkaKodu = marka.MarkaKod  
inner join renkkod on renkkod.renkkodu = renkkod_has_marka.renkkod_RenkKodu  
inner join marka_has_urun on marka_has_urun.marka_MarkaKod = marka.MarkaKod 
inner join urun on urun.urunKodu = marka_has_urun.urun_UrunKodu   
inner join stoktablosu on stoktablosu.BarkodNo = stoktablosu_has_marka.stoktablosu_BarkodNo  
and stoktablosu.BarkodNo = stokguncelleme.BarkodNo
and stoktablosu.renk_renkkodu = renkkod.renkkodu 
and stoktablosu.model_modelkod = model.modelkod
and stoktablosu.urun_urunkodu = urun.urunKodu  
inner join toptanfiyat on toptanfiyat.BarkodNo = stoktablosu.BarkodNo 
where stokguncelleme.adeti != '0' 
and stoktablosu.BarkodNo  = '01012340138483814İY'  
and marka.markaAd != ' ' and urun.UrunGrubu != ' ' and model.Modelkod != ' ' and stoktablosu.Beden != ' ' and renkkod.RenkAdi != ' ' and stoktablosu.StokYeri != ' ' and model.sezon != ' '
```

Comment: sorry if i'm bothered you but now i got this message: 
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'stoktablosu.BarkodNo' in 'on clause'

Comment: Verify is `stoktablosu` table containing `BarkodNo` column? make sure, column names are case sensitive (In Linux/Unix based system)

Comment: @user3637298: Perhaps you should add the missing table through another INNER JOIN clause instead of the way this answer suggests but I agree with the answerer's main point: **you need to include the missing table** into your query.

Comment: I'm sure stoktablosu has BarkodNo column and all cases are true.

Comment: I'm not sure, but may be because in join you are mentioning `stoktablosu` table after its being referred in previous join. Try changing order of join.

Comment: here its getting referenced before join `inner join toptanfiyat on toptanfiyat.BarkodNo = stoktablosu.BarkodNo 
inner join stoktablosu ...`

Comment: I've updated my answer, try given query and let me know what happens

Comment: but you're adding an inner join after where ?? when i wrote this i got syntax error for inner join

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't observed `where` clause, just place that inner join before `where` clause. I've updated answer

Comment: i'm getting same error again:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'stokguncelleme.BarkodNo' in 'on clause'

Comment: This time its asking for column `BarkodNo` in table `stokguncelleme`, is this table too having that column? verify that

Comment: when i remove following code it works but that's not the what i want:
`
and stoktablosu.BarkodNo = stokguncelleme.BarkodNo
and stoktablosu.renk_renkkodu = renkkod.renkkodu 
and stoktablosu.model_modelkod = model.modelkod
and stoktablosu.urun_urunkodu = urun.urunKodu
`